# How to Accept File and string data from Post Request in ASP.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a Reactjs app and post a file and a string as follow to ASP.Net Core 2.0 back end api project. I wanted to post a file and a string value to the back end. But it always show error.

```
                f.append("File",filesArray[i][0]);
                f.append("member_code", this.state.member_code);
                axios.post(apiBaseUrl
                    , f, {
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    var result = response.data;
                    if(result[0].status == "1")
                    {
                        this.state.filesNames.push(result[0].filename);
                        if((i +1) == filesArray.length){
                            window.HideModal();
                            this.setState({filesPreview: null, filesToBeSent: null});
                            this.props.onClick(this.state.filesNames);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

In my ASP.Net core project I tried as below:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(FileUploadViewModel[] model)
        {
            var file = model.File;
            var member_code = "test";
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "uploadFiles/member_files/" + member_code);
                bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);

                if (!exists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
            }

            return clsCommonFunctions.ConstructFileUploadResponse(clsConfig.status_success, file.FileName);
        }
```

But in the ASP.Net core function, I cannot accept both File and string value that I passed as multipart/form-data.

Anyone advise me how can I accept file and a string value as FormData in ASP.Net Core project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) helped me a lot.
I just solved my problem by using [FromBody] attribute to fetch specific value from Request Form-Data. And the final code is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] FileUploadViewModel model, [FromForm] string member_code)
        {
            var file = model.File;

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "uploadFiles/member_files/" + member_code);
                bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);

                if (!exists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
            }

            return clsCommonFunctions.ConstructFileUploadResponse(clsConfig.status_success, file.FileName);
        }
```